# Javascript - ANTLR grammar to PEG conversion

Tags: java, javascript

I have Antlr grammar which is being used for parsing things on Java side, now want to use same grammar to parse things on browser. So like to know if there is any converter available for antlr grammar to peg.js grammar.

using antlr grammar with javascript has issues with version #3 and #4 as I read.
OR 
any other suggestion to handle this situation, as
Cons with this approach are - maintaining 2 grammar (antlr and pegjs)

Comment: Have you got any solution? I'm facing similar problem.

Comment: Unlike ANTLR, PeggyJS currently [doesn't support regular expressions](https://github.com/peggyjs/peggy/issues/154), so you'd need to convert the expressions to PEG grammar rules.